# mongorestore from MongoDB to DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongorestore

I am trying to run mongorestore.exe from a DB dump files of collections into DocumentDB database. I have experience with MongoDB and Azure but not much with DocumentDB.

I am getting an error

> error parsing command line options: unknown option "ssl"

if I use the command from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-migrate).

I have locally installed MongoDB Community Server, "Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit and later, with SSL support x64" of the latest stable version - 3.2.4. 
It looks like the the --ssl command might not be available since the version 3 ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)).

However SSL is enforced by DocumentDB.

Any idea how to migrate an existing database from MongoDB to DocumentDB?The DB is quite large (~GB), hence mongoimport would take too long, we need to user mongorestore, I believe.

Updated, command example:

```
mongorestore.exe --host myhost123.documents.azure.com:10250 -u myhost123 -p somepassword== --db myhost123  --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
```

gives me this error:

> error parsing command line options: unknown option "ssl"

If I remove the two ssl options (--ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates) I get back an error which kind of makes sense as SSL is enforced on Azure DocumentDB:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to show the exact command line you used (obfuscating any real database connection string, password, etc). And also show the exact error. Otherwise, it's really difficult to just guess.

Comment: Thanks, David, I have updated my question

Comment: The `--ssl` option _is_ valid in mongo v3.2; where the linked doc says "_Changed in version 3.0_", the change is that most distributions previously did _not_ support ssl; but from v3.0 onwards most distributions _do_.

Comment: Can you try connecting using the _mongo.exe_ program i.e. the mongo shell? Does the `--ssl` parameter work with that?

Comment: No, mongo.exe does not allow me to call with the --ssl option: "Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--ssl'". However I am sure I have installed the mongo with SSL support (Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit and later, with SSL support x64)

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I installed MongoDB Community Server [Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit and later, with SSL support x64 -3.4.3](https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.3-signed.msi/download) and followed this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-migrate#import-data-to-api-for-mongodb-with-mongorestore) about importing data to API for MongoDB with mongorestore. After some trials, I could restore my local file generated by [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/) to my Azure DocumentDB (MongoDB API) as follows:

[image]

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

I also encountered this error, and found that it was caused by IP Access Control,
 my current IP is not included as the allowed list of client IP addresses. You could find more details about DocumentDB firewall [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-firewall-support).